# При клике на элемент класть его в textarea

Tags: javascript, html, события

Вопрос:

Имеется клавиатура с событием:

```
app.addEventListener('keydown', inputData)
```

Событие корректно работает и выводиться в область `textarea`, но теперь необходимо чтобы при клике мышкой на элемент клавиатуры, данные так же попадали в `textarea`.

HTML:

```
<div class = "app">
  <div class="keyboard">
    <div class="key" data-action="192">ё</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S `data-action="192"` это `event.keyCode` клавиатуры.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это возможно сделать, если можно наглядно, желательно на чиcтом JS.

UPDATE (дополнено из комментария):

У меня имеется электронная клавиатура написанная на HTML + JS.

Один из элементов клавиатуры:

```
<div class="key" data-action="192">ё</div>
```

При клике на него мышкой необходимо чтобы значение попадало в область:

```
<textarea name="screen" id="area" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Введите данные с клавиатуры"></textarea>
<span id="id"></span>
```

Comment: Сделайте в виде сниппета или предоставьте в виде кода

Comment: `чтобы при клике мышкой на элемент клавиатуры` что это значит? как вы мышкой по клавиатуре нажимаете?

Comment: У меня имеется электронная клавиатура написанная на html+js. Вот один из элементов клавиатуры <div class="key" data-action="192">ё</div>. 
При клике на него мышкой необходимо чтобы значение попадало в  в область <textarea name="screen" id="area" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Введите данные с клавиатуры"></textarea><span id="id">

Comment: так а что не получается? вам для каждой кнопки сделать `addEventListener('click', ()=>dowhatyouwant)`

Comment: Сделайте минимальное демо в виде снипетта, уважайте время других людей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea")

const handleClick = event => {
  const value = event.target.dataset.action
  // или
  // const value = event.target.textContent
  textarea.value = value
  // или
  // что бы выводить всю последовательность
  // textarea.value += ` ${value}`
}

document.querySelectorAll(".key").forEach(item => 
  item.addEventListener("click", handleClick))
```

```css
.key {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div class="key" data-action="192">ё</div> 
<textarea name="screen" id="area" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Введите данные с клавиатуры"></textarea>
```