# Как обратиться к элементу формы созданной с помощью document.createElement()?

Tags: javascript, html5

Здраствуйте! Создаю виртуальную клавиатуру и для этого создал массив в котором есть все символы клавиатуры. Кнопки создаются без проблем. Проблема начинается когда я нажимаю на кнопку и хочу, чтобы её символ вписался в поле для ввода. Вот код:

```
function init(){
            for (var i = 0; i < ABC.length;i++){
                if ( i == 12 || i == 22){  //Создаю разделители, чтобы клавиатура выглядела натуральнее
                    var br = document.createElement('br');
                    document.body.append(br);
                }
                var letter = document.createElement('button', value = ABC[i]); 
                letter.innerHTML = ABC[i];
                letter.onclick = function() {
                    mainForm.result.value = "" + value; //Вот не знаю, как обратиться к кнопке, чтобы вывело её символ в поле для ввода
                };
                document.body.append(letter);
            }
        
        }
```

При данном коде при нажатии на кнопку мне выводит символ "Ю", т.к он последний в массиве. Я понимаю почему так происходит (Из-за того, что когда сработает обработчик событий в `value` находится символ "Ю"), но интересно, как получать другие символы?

P.S. На сайте уже в панеле элементов есть такие вот строчки, которые создаются после отработки цикла: `<button is="к">к</button>` может быть можно как-то обратиться в элменту `is` и получить с него символ?

Comment: Возможно дубликат [При клике на эл-т класть его в textarea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1184490/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%bb-%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-textarea)

Comment: После создание клавиатуры создайте уже листенеры и лучше не через is а через [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            letter.onclick = function(e) {
                mainForm.result.value += e.target.innerHTML;
            };
```

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо, теперь осталось понять, почему каждое последующее нажатие на кнопку заменяет собой предыдущую букву, но в любом случае спасибо ещё раз

Comment: Ой, мне очены стыдно за собственную глупость. Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @IRonny Пожалуйста. Успехов.